# CakePHP - trying to include related model data in find('all')

Tags: cakephp

So I am finding some data from one of my models:

```
// Models

class SubjectChange extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Subject', 'User');

}

class Subject extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array('SubjectChange');

    public $belongsTo = array('SubjectGroup');

}


// Controller code to get all SubjectChanges

$subjectChanges = ClassRegistry::init('SubjectChange')->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Subject.name',
        'User.full_name'
    )
));
```

This returns me each SubjectChange like this, which is great:

```
Array
(
    [SubjectChange] => Array
    (
        [id] => 35,
        [subject_group_id] => 5,
        [timestamp] => '2011-10-18 16:52:24'
    )

    [Subject] => Array
    (
        [name] => 'English'
    )

    [User] => Array
    (
        [full_name] => 'John Smith'
    )

)
```

But I want to add to that the name of the SubjectGroup, using the subject_group_id from the SubjectChange part.  The important thing to note here is that the SubjectChange model **does not** have any relationship to the SubjectGroup model, **and** that I can't get it from the Subject because it may have a different subject_group_id currently stored in the database.

I just want to do some sort of join in my query to get the SubjectGroup name from the SubjectChange subject_group_id that I have, to add this data to the above:

```
[SubjectGroup] => Array
    (
        [name] => 'My Group Name'
    )
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: why SubjectChange does not have any association to SubjectGroup? you may do it on-the-fly if you don't want it permanent... but that is the easiest and correct way of doing this

Comment: Yep, just figured that out.  It doesn't have a real association with it, but I have just added it in.  How would I add to the relationship on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to do a complete answer then.

You have 3 way to do this:

the normal and the first one you should use is the associations declare in var hasMany, var BelongsTo, etc...

the second way is to do the first way on the fly

```
 $this->Leader->bindModel(
        array('hasMany' => array(
                'Principle' => array(
                    'className' => 'Principle',
                     //other attributes
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

simply use the bindModel function to do this, you may look more of this [in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly)

The third way is to do a force join in the find, for this you may look [more in the book here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables)

Maybe there is more options, but i don't remember them right now. Anyway this are the ones that are easy enough :)

Hope it helps you